# Capture RTSP in command line

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video, rtsp

I want to continously **capture the rtsp** video(CCTV) in ubuntu. (in Putty)

I have tried to use **OpenCV** in **Python** to open rtsp, however, the program will terminate suddenly.

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://stream_link/")
while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite(name,frame)
```

Then, I turned to use vlc.

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://192.168.1.128:1554/11 --sout=file/ts:/media/path/to/save/location/recording-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").ts -I dummy --stop-time=480 vlc://quit
```

Also, a huge brunch of error.

I am asking for help how can I capture the rtsp in ubuntu in command line. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Using `ffmpeg` is almost always the best idea:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov test.mp4
```

To capture only the first 5 seconds you can use `-t 00:00:05` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -t 00:00:05 test.mp4
```

**Update**: The only thing which comes into my mind why someone downvoted this answer is probably because I didn't write how to segment the received stream continuously, so here is how to do it:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 4 -f segment output%03d.mp4
```

This will receive the rtsp stream and create output000.mp4, output001.mp4 etc. each 4 seconds long.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this only save as video? What if I want to capture its frame, like 5 frames/second?

Comment: Why the down vote? At least write the reason so I can improve the answer.